# Setting default value for properties of Interface?

Tags: c#, oop, class, interface, class-design

I have an Interface which contains one property. I need to set the default value for that property. How to do that?. Also is it good practice to have a default value for a property in Interface? or here using an abstract class instead is a apt one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't set a default value to a property of an interface.

Use abstract class in addition to the interface (which only sets the default value and doesn't implement anything else):

```
    public interface IA {
        int Prop { get; }

        void F();
    }

    public abstract class ABase : IA {
        public virtual int Prop
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public abstract void F();
    }

    public class A : ABase
    {
        public override void F() { }
    }
```

Comment: Petar, Does, Use abstract class in addition to the interface means,i should change the Interface to an abstract class?

Comment: No it means use an abstract class which implements the interface and then extend it.

Answer (score 12):

With C#8, interfaces can have a default implementation.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/

Comment: this does not seem to include default property values, though it does include default property implementations

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces contain no implementation. All they do is state member signatures.

An *implementation* of an interface is free to have whatever default value it likes for any property.

E.g. an abstract class can return a default value for any of it's properties.

Comment: The sentence "Interfaces contain no implementation." is now invalid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#concrete-methods-in-interfaces

Comment: Sure, but I'm not going to go back and update old answers. They have timestamps, as do subsequent versions of languages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with **static** fields.Because, interfaces cannot contains instance fields. Static fields are not instance fields.

Or you can use literal values. For example, I use Age property in interface below.

```
public interface IMyDefault
{
    private static string _name = "Yusif";

    // Has default implementation
    string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    int Age { get => 18; }

    // Hasn't default implementation
    string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class MyDefault : IMyDefault
{

    // We only implement Surname in MyDefault.cs
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

But, you can access default implemented properties only after cast object to interface.

For example:

Code below **will not compile**

```
MyDefault myDefault1 = new MyDefault();

Console.WriteLine(myDefault1.Name);
```

Code below **will compile**

```
IMyDefault myDefault2 = new MyDefault();

Console.WriteLine(myDefault2.Name);
```